# Delphi SOAP Server - Document/Literal - Possible?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

We're using Delphi2005 with Delphi2007 patches, also experimenting with DelphiXE SOAP libraries.  But I've hit a snag... 
We've got an internal service that our app has been consuming for a year now. The service uses document/literal convention, and is used by several systems on several platforms (java, .Net, and ours - Delphi2005).  Now we need to become a publisher and not just a consumer.  So we're building a server service.  And the WSDL is coming out wrong.  I consume the "official" WSDL as document/literal, and when I try to serve it back as a service, it comes out as RPC style.  Even though I've set the options of the HTTPSoapPascalInvoker.Converter to be [soLiteralParams, soDocument].
Now that I do some more searching, I find statements like this:
"Delphi for Win32 does not support creating Document Literal Soap Servers."
[ http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Pascal/Delphi/Q_22664248.html ]

That quote is a few years old. Does anyone know if it still applies?
I AM in a position to move this portion of the project to Delphi2010 or XE if necessary, but I'd rather not (throws a wrench into our automated build process).  Including the SOAP libs is ok, and we already do that.

So, if anyone knows whether it's possible to write a Win32 Delphi web service in 2005, 2010 or XE that will produce a WSDL that conforms to document/literal, I'd be very, very happy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

AFAIK, last time I checked, the stock Delphi SOAP Server was limited to RPC and the "official" motto was that you could use Delphi Prism to build your server (i.e. we won't add Doc|Lit in Delphi).
However, you can use the latest RemObjects SDK (not free) to build a Doc|lit SOAP Server, or use IndySOAP (open Source), but I don't know if there is a version compatible with D2009 and up (Unicode/Indy 10)...

Comment: Thanks. Fears are confirmed, but it's good to see that there are some options.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [WST](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Web_Service_Toolkit). It is compatible with Delphi. Better check out from svn as the 0.5 release is actualy outdated.