# Does any version of Delphi (not .net) support Document/literal or RPC/literal binding SOAP service?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

I have a SOAP server API for some of our services and one of the clients said that they won't integrate with services not offering at least WS-I Basic Profile compliance binding.

So, the question is does any version of Delphi support Document/literal or RPC/literal binding?

**Edit:** Looks like RemObjects support Document/literal or RPC/literal.

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308343/delphi-soap-server-document-literal-possible... Although not exactly the same question, the answer still applies AFAIK.

Comment: it would be interesting to know if the Free Pascal Web Service Toolkit (which also works with Delphi) has this feature

Comment: I'm a customer of the `RemObjects` products using Regular Win32 Delphi (not .net/prism) and I can confirm that you can write SOAP servers using it that support more features than the built in SOAP RTL supports.  I have not tried RPC/Literal or Document/literal though, so I can't talk about that. I can point you to the place you could ask that and get an answer though:  http://connect.remobjects.com/

Comment: @François this question is more about WS-I Basic support, the doc/literal or rpc/literal is a minor part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I recently dove into the Delphi code because I could not consume the MS Exchange Server WDSL (which seems to be SOAP 1.1 "document/literal wrapped").
I'm not an expert in this, but I came across this code in the Delphi XE2 unit Soap.OPToSOAPDomConv which does not look correct to me:

```
if not IsRPC then
begin
  if IsBareLiteral then
  begin
    [snip]
  end
  else
  begin
    // IsWrappedLiteral !
```

with

```
function TSOAPDomConvHelper.IsRPC: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not (soDocument in Options);
end;

function TSOAPDomConvHelper.IsBareLiteral: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Options * [soDocument, soLiteralParams] = [soDocument, soLiteralParams];
end;

function TSOAPDomConvHelper.IsWrappedLiteral: Boolean;
begin
  Result := Options * [soDocument, soLiteralParams] = [soDocument];
end;
```

Although your question is about WSDL generation (not about its consumption), the above suggests to me that "document/literal wrapped" is not properly supported.

Jan

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996466.aspx#rpc_literal_topic5) (April 2003):

> **WS-I Basic Profile and RPC/literal**
>
> Unfortunately, the WS-I Basic Profile explicitly permits the use of
>   both document/literal and RPC/literal. Given the above analysis, I
>   believe having two message formats is unnecessary and ultimately does
>   not help interoperability. Hopefully, most if not all Web service
>   developers will ignore RPC/literal and provide the necessary feedback
>   to WS-I to fix this in a future version of the Basic Profile.

So I would suggest to ignore RPC/literal completely.

Also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile points to different versions of WS-I Basic - 1.2 (finalized in November 2010) and 2.0 (published in November 2010) seem to be the latest versions. I would check which version level is expected from your communication partner.

---

**Solution**

Move the web service from Delphi to a WS-I compliant framework, with Delphi still providing the logic but talking internally over IPC with the new framework.

The majority of the [compliant frameworks listed in the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-I_Basic_Profile) are open source, have good documentation and a huge installed user base, so they are production-ready and stable.

In the long run, using a compliant framework will cause less hazzle and workarounds, and also allow to support the other WS-I standard with little additional work.